Mixed Effects models approach?
I've been debating on a more deliberate diving into working with mixed models but I am slowly feeling overwhelmed. I've been going through resources (tutorials, webpages, books, etc) and have feeling like I'm missing something …maybe it's me overthinking it or maybe it's me just not understanding about model fit and “validation”. Also, the variety of mixed model packages (with varying levels of the need for other packages and dependencies) has got me flustered. I put validation in quotes (because it can mean lots of things to different people), in this case, I was thinking more like fitting assumptions of the statistical test.
Something else adding to my frustration and confusion is the naming convention, or lack thereof, for these types of models. It feels sort of like any combination of model, mixed, effect, linear, and sometimes general or generalized gets tossed together. Sort of like …
word.salad <- expand.grid(word1 = as.factor(c("mixed","effect","linear")),
                          word2 = as.factor(c("mixed","effect","linear")),
                          word3 = as.factor(c("mixed","effect","linear")))

word.salad <- word.salad[word.salad$word1!=word.salad$word2&
                        word.salad$word1!=word.salad$word3&
                        word.salad$word2!=word.salad$word3,]

Here is my situation, I have water quality data across a large lake. The assumption is that a specific water quality parameter (concentrate and frequency of exceeding a specific limit) is generally driven by lake water level and this relationship varies across different zones of the lake. Ultimately, these relationships/models will be used to evaluate restoration planning so there is a predictive component to them as well.
I would suspect that generalized linear mixed models (GLMM) would be a good fit for this type of analysis/evaluation. I'm especially interested in using GLMs due to the ability to use different distributions (more so than just normal/gaussian) and link functions. Some other work on these drivers and responses indicates that the observed data follow a gamma or Tweedie distribution moreso than normal. So far I've gotten the “feeling” that GLMM or mixed models in general are more geared toward test effects more so than predictions. While the effect is important I'm also interested in model fit, as in a model that can pass the laugh test to evaluate different simulated scenarios and is somewhat relatable to real-world examples.
Given the insight presented here by Dr Bolker I think the lme4 package using the glmer() function is probably the best bet and is the most robust method.
Something that has gotten me wrapped around the axel is specifying the random effect. In this case the zones are the random effect, right? I was also think that both slope and intercept would vary between these zones or at a minimum just slope. Is that too far of a stretch (for the method, given the data)? Something else to consider for future analyses is a seasonal component (maybe ripe for random intercept?). Again, after going through this resource by Dr Bolker, I definitely have a random effect (I think).
For model validation, as in how well does the model perform in a predictive way, I was thinking of bootstrapping rather than the usual splitting data into testing and training. Mostly because the observed dataset doesn't lend itself well to splitting the data due to other factors (changes in system inputs and how water levels were managed over time).
For me to contextualize and test an analysis workflow I put together the following reproducible example that somewhat resembles the observed data.
Synthetic Dataset creation
set.seed(123)
n.sample <-  48

## simulate predictor values
xval <- cos(seq(0,3,length.out=12)*pi)
offset <- c(12.2,9.7,8.7,10.0)# rnorm(4,12,2.5)
xval <- c(xval+offset[1],xval+offset[2],xval+offset[3],xval+offset[4])

## Simulate response values
mu <- c(30,10,15,60)
sigma <- rlnorm(4,1)# c(8,5,8,10)
beta <- runif(4,0,6)
y1 <- rgamma(n.sample,(mu[1]/sigma[1])^2,mu[1]/sigma[1]^2)+beta[1]*xval
y2 <- rgamma(n.sample,(mu[2]/sigma[2])^2,mu[2]/sigma[2]^2)+beta[1]*xval
y3 <- rgamma(n.sample,(mu[3]/sigma[3])^2,mu[3]/sigma[3]^2)+beta[1]*xval
y4 <- rgamma(n.sample,(mu[4]/sigma[4])^2,mu[4]/sigma[4]^2)+beta[1]*xval

# time component
mon.CY <- expand.grid(month=1:12,CY = paste0("Y",1:4))

dat <- rbind(
  cbind(mon.CY,data.frame(value = y1,xval = xval,zone = "a")),
  cbind(mon.CY,data.frame(value = y2,xval = xval,zone = "b")),
  cbind(mon.CY,data.frame(value = y3,xval = xval,zone = "c")),
  cbind(mon.CY,data.frame(value = y4,xval = xval,zone = "d"))
)
dat$zone <- as.factor(dat$zone)
cols <- c("red","blue","green","grey")
plot(value~xval,dat,pch=21,bg=cols[dat$zone],cex=1.5)
hist(dat$value)

GLMM workflow
library(lme4)
library(DHARMa)
library(performance)

## random intercept
mod <- glmer(value~xval+(1|zone),family=gaussian(link="log"),data = dat)
#Null model
mod0 <- glmer(value~(1|zone),family=gaussian(link="log"),data = dat); 
anova(mod,mod0);

## random slope? (this might be the one??)
mod <- glmer(value~xval+(0+xval|zone),family=gaussian(link="log"),data = dat)
#Null model
mod0 <- glmer(value~(0+xval|zone),family=gaussian(link="log"),data = dat);
anova(mod,mod0)
summary(mod)

# dispersion check
performance::check_overdispersion(mod)
performance::check_homogeneity(mod)

# residual evaluation
simulationOutput  <-  DHARMa::simulateResiduals(mod)
plot(simulationOutput)
hist(simulationOutput)

plotResiduals(simulationOutput, form = dat$zone)

# Model summary and interrogation
summary(mod)
anova(mod)
lme4::VarCorr(mod)
car::Anova(mod)

Based on the diagnostics the models look good right? Granted this is a very basic (minimal random noise) example. At this point I'm kind at the point of wandering to figure out the next step. Is there a test to compare groups in GLMM? The first step would be to look at the different model coefficients right?
coef(mod)

Obviously, evaluating model fit is important (to quell those people looking for R^2 values), how do you get an R2-like value (I know the traditional R2 value is not correct here)? Is the comparison of null deviance and residual deviation correct ... or calculating the McFaddens pseudo R2? If so I've seen it represented a couple of different ways.
1 - (deviance(mod)/deviance(mod0))

but also
1-(as.numeric(logLik(mod))/as.numeric(logLik(mod0)))

I know this is a long post/question and more suited to be broken up but wanted to broadcast to the larger community for thoughts and input. As I'm finalizing this post I realize it might be better to be a blog post (maybe it will be revised with input from comments/responses as a blog post).
Thanks in advance!!
Next evolution (added after posting)
After some rooting around the inter-webs, I came across another fantastic blog post by the one and only Gavin Simpson about mixed models (and how to do them in the mgcv) package. In his blog post Using random effects in GAMs with mgcv, he demonstrates the comparability of mixed-effects models using lme4::lmer(...) and mgcv::gam(...). The terminology issue(s), model fit and other issues about interrogating the models raised above are smoothed over (pun intended) ... partly due to my familiarity with mgcv but more importantly the way Dr Simpson explains things! Below is some example code (adapted from the blog post for the example above).
library(mgcv)
library(gratia)
## random intercept -------------------------------------------------
mod_gamm1 <- gam(value ~ xval + s(zone,bs="re"),
                family=gaussian(link="log"),
                data = dat,method = 'REML')
summary(mod_gamm1)
variance_comp(mod_gamm1)

## random slope -----------------------------------------------------
mod_gamm2 <- gam(value ~ xval + s(zone,xval,bs="re"),
                family=gaussian(link="log"),
                data = dat,method = 'REML')
summary(mod_gamm2)
variance_comp(mod_gamm2)

# Random slope and intercept ----------------------------------------
mod_gamm3 <- gam(value ~ xval + s(zone,bs="re")+s(zone,xval,bs="re"),
                 family=gaussian(link="log"),
                 data = dat,method = 'REML')
gam.check(mod_gamm3)
testResiduals(simulateResiduals(mod_gamm3))

summary(mod_gamm3)
variance_comp(mod_gamm3)
edf(mod_gamm3)

Things seem pretty streamlined with the mgcv package but a couple of questions pop up. First, how does the deviance explained/R^2 relate to the condition and marginal R2 values? Secondly, and more importantly, does it matter?

If we were being old-school acolytes of Scheffe's random effects, then no, zone would not be considered a random effect as the sample of zones you have are not a random sample of possible zones from the population (could such a population even be said to exist? Depends on how these zones were chosen/delineated).
Then again, treating smooths in a penalized splines framework (a la mgcv) as random effects would also go against the definition of old-school random effects.
Myself, as you might have anticipated, subscribe to the new school of random effects, seeing them as a vehicle for computing quantities of interest rather than as something to be discussed in more philosophical surroundings.
One thing to consider though is whether you want point estimates for your zone's or are you more interested in the population values, with zones being seen as random variations around these values? From what you describe, zone might best be treated as a fixed effect if you have specific interest in those zones from a conservation or restoration perspective. Typically, random effects are used when the data are clustered in some way (by subject, or as here by zone) and you don't typically care about the specific subjects or zones sampled.
Another thing to consider is whether there is a spatial component to the variation among zones? If you have enough zones and they are spread about the lake, then treating the zones as all having their own mean irrespective of spatial relationship (as you would if you modelled them as a fixed or random effect) would model the spatial variation in the data but you could do it more efficiently (and learning some else about your system) if you modelled the zone means spatially, either via a spatial smooth (I'm thinking a 2d thin plate spline) or if the zones are more like US counties, via a Gaussian Markov random field (via bs = "mrf").
Practically speaking, unless you need smooth functions, you would be better off using software designed to fit random effects; here I would consider the glmmTMB package by Ben Bolker & Mollie Brooks, which works quite like lme4 but has more distributions (Tweedie is available for example) and allows for correlation structures in the covariance structure, unlike lme4. If you need smooth functions of covariates, then mgcv and it's gam() and bam() functions would be good choices, but you are limited if you want correlation structures within the model covariance, or you can ignore them and estimate the smooths / parameters using method = "NCV".
The whole distinction between marginal or conditional anything with a GAM(M) just makes my brain melt; if you want some quantity that is marginal or conditional on the random effects, do the random effects include the wiggly bits of the smooths? If they don't, why treat the random effects different to the wiggly bits? What if I write the random effect as a penalized spline? These distinctions crop up in many places; marginal or conditional AIC for example. Some researchers at U Waterloo in Canada have produced some interesting work recently on conditional vs marginal interpretations of GAMs, which I still need to read properly to understand what they are doing. The deviance reported in the summary() is conditional upon any random effects in the model, for what it is worth. I probably wouldn't use the adjusted R^2 for non-Gaussian models.
As for your GLMM example code, I would probably fit (1 + xval | zone) instead of the uncorrelated random effects you used, unless you centred xval.
performance found a heterogeneity in group (zone) variances (in my sample) but the Levene's test run by DHARMa does suggest some differences in variance not accounted for in the model; so that's something to consider and fix.
Most importantly, don't model these data as Gaussian with a log link; presumably you were thinking about some lake water parameter for the response here, and if so, we know from first principles that such variables cannot be negative and have will typically exhibit some non-constant mean-variance relationship. I typically approach such modelling tasks with a Tweedie or a Gamma conditional distribution in mind (or log-normal, but fitted as an actual log-normal). If there are zeroes in the response, I would very doubt these are real zeroes for any water chemistry parameter, so at that point you'd need to consider including the censoring in the model.

This may sound like a tangent, but is an alternative way of approaching the question.
Huang, et al, talk about the idea of "catalytic priors" which is basically augmenting data with simulated data from a simpler model applied to the same data.
A mixed model can then be considered like an ensemble of a simple model and a complex model.
https://www.pnas.org/doi/full/10.1073/pnas.1920913117
